# Server returning b'\xe....' instead of actual time for Time Protocol

Tags: python-3.x, linux, networking, debian

I've been trying to implement Time Protocol in debian as a client.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import socket


TCP_IP = 'server-name'
TCP_PORT = 37
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
MESSAGE = b''

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.send(MESSAGE)
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)

s.close()

print ("received data:",  data.decode("utf-16"))
```

This is how I was told to implement, however I am getting the value as two question marks.

If I don't decode it prints b'\xe22e\xd1' or something like that

Don't know how to get the time. Or is this how I am supposed to for Time Protocol?

Comment: It appears you are attempting to use the ancient Daytime protocol, not any of the Time protocol or Network Time Protocol versions. It is quite likely that you are not going to find a server that implements the Daytime protocol.

Comment: @RonMaupin My mistake I put 13 instead of 37 as port in the question, I was implementing both time protocol and daytime protocol just for trial. Everything worked fine for daytime protocol. Time protocol wasn't working and was giving me the wrong results. I mean, for port 37, Time protocol it was giving me that value. b'\xe22'

Comment: The problem is that Daytime will give you a string, but Time protocol returns a big-endian 32-bit unsigned integer, not a string.

Comment: @RonMaupin So how do i get back the original characters from b'\xe22'. I know that it's returning time, cause the character at the end changes every second. I used decode("utf-8", "ignore") and did something like that and that gave me '\xe22', it made it string, but I want the original time, so that I can set up the system time.

Comment: Those are not characters, not text, you cannot read it with a string or decode it with any version of UTF. Again, it is a big-endian, 32-bit, unsigned integer. You need to read it as such, fix the endianess to your host, and then you can convert the integer to a text string.

Comment: @RonMaupin Thanks bro, I did convert it into integers and now I am getting a value -
(57907, 36944). The second value varies per second. How do i convert this one now?